# Autolayout errors and identifiers

Tags: ios, user-interface, autolayout

I get an Autolayout error that I do not understand:

```
2013-03-14 18:30:48.842 driver[7177:907] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1ede73e0 UILabel:0x1ede4320.top == PriceCell:0x1edcd0c0.top + 160>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1ede7460 V:[UILabel:0x1ede4320]-(7)-[UIImageView:0x1ede45d0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1ede74a0 UIImageView:0x1ede45d0.centerY == UIImageView:0x1f856810.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1ede7880 UIImageView:0x1f856810.top == PriceCell:0x1edcd0c0.top + 30>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1ede78c0 UIImageView:0x1f856810.bottom == PriceCell:0x1edcd0c0.bottom>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1f83f340 h=--& v=--& V:[PriceCell:0x1edcd0c0(300)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1ede7460 V:[UILabel:0x1ede4320]-(7)-[UIImageView:0x1ede45d0]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

The problem: From the error list I cannot determine which ui elements autolayout is referring to. So I turned back to my Storyboard and assigned each UI element in my tableviewcell an Identifier in the field Restoration Id. I've read somewhere that the hex number in the error messages are then replaced by the names I assigned to the corresponding ui elements. But unfortunately this is not happening. So what am I doing wrong here, or what am I missing?

Comment: Setting the identifier should work. But you can always run `po 0x1ede4320` in the debugger or even `po [0x1ede4320 text]` or `p [0x1ede4320 frame]` to see if that helps you identify them.

Comment: No way to set view Identifier in iOS. Major fail, Apple!

Answer (score 0):

I’ve checked the layout constraints breaking which is causing error.

If I am not wrong then your layout might looks like:
[image]

So its looks like you have set constraints like:

```
•   Vertical space between cell top and label top is 160. So your label will be 160 px down from cell top.
•   Then you have set vertical space between label and imageView1 is 7 px.
•   Then you made centre Y between imageView1 and imageView2 to 0 px. So their centre will be same.
•   Then you set vertical space between imageView2 and cell top is 30 px.
•   Then you set vertical space between image view bottom and cell bottom is 0 px.
•   It seems that your cell height is 300 px.
```

All this constraint are breaking just to satisfy your one constraint.

So what happens here that to satisfy the constraint of “ 160 + label.height + 7 + UIImageView1.height “.

Well it seems that you cell height is less than the total height of label + imageView1 + 160 px of y + 7.

It seems it total is getting more that 300 which is height of your cell and your both imageView1 and imageView2 centre Y are trying to match centre to 0.